# How avoid that the custom user setting influence the font size in the app

Tags: android

I want to avoid that the setting preferences of the user for the fonts influence the font size of the various TextView etc  in my app.

What is the best way?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to allow the users to influence the display in your app by providing appropriate layouts for different sizes?

Comment: @Gorgsenegger Not in any case, I want to include custom fonts and custom font setting in my app, so allow the user system setting to influence font behavior could lead to graphic issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to avoid that the setting preferences of the user for the fonts influence the font size of the various TextView etc in my app.

Users will only change their font scale if they feel that larger (or, possibly smaller) fonts improve their use of their device. Your app should adjust to match, by using `sp` units for text sizes. Users may dislike your app if your app refuses to honor their request.

> What is the best way?

Do not use `sp` units for text sizes, and be ready for negative reviews on the Play Store.

Comment: There's more info on the units linked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2025282/346232

Comment: This is wrong
"Do not use sp units for text sizes, and be ready for negative reviews on the Play Store."
If you include custom fonts in your app the font size setting are different and require different setting, setting that I will include in my app, so use sp could lead to graphic issues.